# Creating an Android Bitmap from an Amazon S3 object with BitmapFactory?

Tags: android, bitmap, amazon-s3

I have an image in the S3 server stored with the .bmp extension and retrieve the object with a call to getObject(). I then instantiate an InputStream with a call to getObjectContent(). I'm trying to create a bitmap object by passing the inputStream to BitmapFactory's decodeStream() method. As stated in the docs, it is returning null (instead of a Bitmap) presumably because the inputStream "cannot be used to decode a bitmap". Any ideas on why this is happening? Alternatively, ideas on other ways to download a photo from S3 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much!

```
GetObjectRequest getPhoto = new GetObjectRequest(MainActivity.USERS_BUCKET_NAME, finalList.get(i));
S3Object photoObject = s3.getObject(getPhoto);
InputStream inputStream = photoObject.getObjectContent();
//process inputStream
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream); //this is returning null
//close inputStream
try {
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by using the Apache Commons IOUtils library - I converted the inputstream into a byte array with IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream) and passed that into BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(); it no longer returns null.